# желтый input в maxthon

Tags: css

в брузере maxthon inputы в которых при загрузке страницы уже введен текст,покрашены желтым цветом и никак этот цвет не хорчет меняться. прочитал про `-webkit-autofill` (правда это в chromе) и задание большой внутренней тени -ничего не помогает. ктонибудь сталкивался?

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего это поля заполненные автозаполнением. Это никак не определяется css кодом страницы. В лучшем случае этот цвет можно менять где-то в настройках maxthon'а

Comment: то есть, вообще нет никакой возможности это поменять? а если создается темный шаблон, как нужно выкручиваться? странно, что разработчики браузера так поступили...